# Suma Acumulativa por Grupos en pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, sum

necesito ir acumulando las cifras por año de mi dataframe, de tal forma que cuando se cambie de año no me acumule lo del año anterior.

El dataframe del que parto contiene cifras por trimestre y necesito ir acumulando de la siguiente forma: para el año 1 Trim1, Trim1+Trim2, Trim1+Trim2+Trim3, Trim1+Trim2+Trim3+Trim4 y lo mismo para los sucesivos años.

El dataframe inicial se llama 'pyg_agregada'y contiene los siguientes datos:

```
Concepto                        ED. Cuenta de resultados. Residentes en España                                                    
2010-03-31                                         19311033.0                       
2010-06-30                                         19215002.0                       
2010-09-30                                         19027297.0                       
2010-12-31                                         19537833.0                       
2011-03-31                                         19766815.0                       
2011-06-30                                         20816617.0                       
2011-09-30                                         21464932.0                       
2011-12-31                                         21914540.0
```

Escribo el siguiente código para ir acumulando las cifras:

```
pyg_acumulada = pyg_agregada.cumsum(axis = 0)
```

Obteniendo el siguiente resultado:

```
Concepto                             ED. Cuenta de resultados. Residentes en España                                               
2010-03-31                                         19311033.0                       
2010-06-30                                         38526035.0                       
2010-09-30                                         57553332.0                       
2010-12-31                                         77091165.0                       
2011-03-31                                         **96857980.0**                       
2011-06-30                                        117674597.0                       
2011-09-30                                        139139529.0                       
2011-12-31                                        161054069.0
```

El problema que no consigo resolver es cómo hacer para que cuando se cambia de año no se acumulen las cifras anteriores y solo se acumule trimestre a trimestre para cada año. Es decir, necesitaría obtener el siguiente resultado:

```
Concepto                             ED. Cuenta de resultados. Residentes en España                                               
2010-03-31                                         19311033.0                       
2010-06-30                                         38526035.0                       
2010-09-30                                         57553332.0                       
2010-12-31                                         77091165.0                       
2011-03-31                                         **19766815.0**                       
2011-06-30                                         40583432.0                       
2011-09-30                                         62048364.0                       
2011-12-31                                         83962904.0
```

Como se ve, cuando cambia de 2010 a 2011 quiero conseguir que no se acumule y se conserve la cifra inicial a partir de la cual empezar a acumular de nuevo en el siguiente trimestre.

No consigo obtener un código que me hago esto, ¿podríais ayudarme? Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes hacerlo utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) agrupando por año (Para eso Concepto debe ser de tipo datetime) y luego utilizando [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) para sumar el acumulado

Utilizando los datos de tu pregunta (Cree un `dataframe` en el archivo "sample2.csv"):

```
    Concepto    ED. Cuenta de resultados. Residentes en España
0   2010-03-31  19311033.0
1   2010-06-30  19215002.0
2   2010-09-30  19027297.0
3   2010-12-31  19537833.0
4   2011-03-31  19766815.0
5   2011-06-30  20816617.0
6   2011-09-30  21464932.0
7   2011-12-31  21914540.0
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
df['Concepto'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Concepto'])
df['Acumulado'] = df.groupby([df['Concepto'].dt.year])['ED. Cuenta de resultados. Residentes en España'].cumsum()
```

Al imprimir `df` obtenemos:

```
    Concepto    ED. Cuenta de resultados. Residentes en España  Acumulado
0   2010-03-31  19311033.0                                      19311033.0
1   2010-06-30  19215002.0                                      38526035.0
2   2010-09-30  19027297.0                                      57553332.0
3   2010-12-31  19537833.0                                      77091165.0
4   2011-03-31  19766815.0                                      19766815.0
5   2011-06-30  20816617.0                                      40583432.0
6   2011-09-30  21464932.0                                      62048364.0
7   2011-12-31  21914540.0                                      83962904.0
```

Comment: hola @HeytalePazguato, también he intentado ejecutar tú código de la siguiente forma:                                                                                  
pyg_agregada['Concepto'] = pd.to_datetime(pyg_agregada['Concepto'])
pyg_agregada['Acumulado'] = df.groupby([pyg_agregada['Concepto'].dt.year])['ED. Cuenta de resultados. Residentes en España'].cumsum()
pero me da el siguiente error: 'Column not found: ED. Cuenta de resultados. Residentes en España'

Comment: ¿La columna con los valores numéricos como se llama? Yo puse ese nombre porque viene de tus datos, pero si se llama diferente debes reemplazar el texto

Comment: Se llama así...

Comment: ¿Posiblemente tiene espacios extra al inicio o al final? En los datos de tu pregunta veo que tiene muchos espacios en blanco al final, en el archivo de prueba los eliminé

Comment: he probado también de la siguiente forma y me da el mismo error                         pyg_agregada['Concepto'] = pd.to_datetime(pyg_agregada['Concepto'])
pyg_agregada['Acumulado'] = df.groupby([pyg_agregada['Concepto'].dt.year])[pyg_agregada.columns[1]].cumsum()
print(pyg_agregada)

Comment: ¿Podrías abrir el archivo donde tienes los datos, copiar y pegar en un comentario la primera fila con los nombres de las columnas?

Comment: Eso está muy raro, ¿`pyg_agregada` tiene todas las columnas que pusiste en tu pregunta? Tal vez hay alguna otra operación en tu código anterior a esas líneas que elimina o sobreescribe las columnas? He copiado y pegado el código de tu comentario y renombré mi `df` por `pyg_agregada` y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Concepto ED. Cuenta de resultados. Residentes en España ED. Cuenta de resultados. Residentes en España. Costes financieros ED. Cuenta de resultados. Residentes en España. Margen de intereses ED. Cuenta de resultados. Residentes en España. Rendimiento intrumentos capital y otros productos y gastos ED. Cuenta de resultados. Residentes en España. Productos cartera de valores. Resultados cartera renta variable ED. Cuenta de resultados. Residentes en España. Otros productos y gastos ordinarios. Comisiones. Neto

Comment: perdona @HeytalePazguato es que voy más lenta que tú al responderte. pyg_agregada tiene muchas más columnas. Solo puse la primera a modo ejemplo para luego aplicarlo a todo el dataframe

Comment: Ah ok, tienes varias columnas con el mismo nombre, cierto? Si es así al importarse `pandas` les agrega un sufijo para diferenciarlas por defecto es un punto y un valor numérico, por lo que tal vez tu columna se llame `ED. Cuenta de resultados. Residentes en España.1`. Al obtener el `dataframe` directamente del archivo, si lo imprimes el nombre de la columna se mantiene como lo pusiste en tu publicación? (Lo siento, escribo muy rápido)

Comment: Cree un [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245455/suma-acumulativa-pandas) para que podamos resolverlo ahí, por favor entra

Comment: jajaja, no no, gracias por seguir respondiéndome. Las columnas se llaman de forma distinta. He probado a ejecutar el código línea a línea en celdas distintas y me funciona. Si quiero conseguir el acumulado de todas las columnas, ¿tengo que ir columna por columna o lo puedo hacer para todas a la vez?

Comment: Entra al chat de mi comentario anterior y ahí lo resolvemos

Comment: ayy madre, si es que soy... no se contestar en el chat, por eso no te estoy respondiendo, perdoname. Creo que es porque no tengo 20 reputaciones...

Comment: En un comentario anterior puse un link a un chat, oprime la palabra [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245455/suma-acumulativa-pandas)

Comment: Perdonadme, que ayer ya no pude conectarme. Pero es lo que os decía que no puedo hablar por el chat porque no tengo 20 reputaciones

Comment: Ya te voté en tu pregunta para que puedas ver el chat con la solución de múltiples columnas

Comment: Mil gracias, ya he visto en el chat la solución y por fin me funciona!!!! Buen fin de semana!

Answer (score 0):

Para lograrlo, puedes usar el método [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), que te permite agrupar los datos. Esto devuelve un objeto especial que representa un DataFrame agrupado.
Dicho objeto tiene el método [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html). La función auxiliar que recibe dicho método debe recibir un argumento que será cada grupo en forma de DataFrame. Luego se encargará de concatenar todo lo devuelto por la función auxiliar.

El plan sería agrupar al dataframe por año y a cada grupo modificarle la columna numero para que sea una suma acumulativa. Luego devolver el grupo modificado, para que Pandas pueda concatenar todos los DataFrames.

###### Código

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

records = [(fecha, index) for index, fecha in enumerate((datetime(2019, 3, 6),
                                                         datetime(2019, 6, 6),
                                                         datetime(2019, 9, 6),
                                                         datetime(2020, 4, 6),
                                                         datetime(2021, 3, 6),
                                                         datetime(2021, 6, 6)), start=1)]


def auxfunc(group):
    group.numero = group.numero.cumsum()
    return group

df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=["concepto", "numero"])

nuevo_df = df.groupby(df.concepto.dt.year).apply(auxfunc)

print(df)
print()
print(nuevo_df)
```

###### Produce

```
    concepto  numero
0 2019-03-06       1
1 2019-06-06       2
2 2019-09-06       3
3 2020-04-06       4
4 2021-03-06       5
5 2021-06-06       6

    concepto  numero
0 2019-03-06       1
1 2019-06-06       3
2 2019-09-06       6
3 2020-04-06       4
4 2021-03-06       5
5 2021-06-06      11
```

*Nota*: Para que esto funcione correctamente, la columna concepto debe ser un objeto fecha. Si no lo es, te recomiendo convertirlo a fecha previamente.

Comment: Si la respuesta de HeytalePazguato no te funciona tampoco, podrías aclararnos a ambos cual es el nuevo error por favor?

Comment: Seguramente utilizaste el código directamente sin modificarlo, Dante utilizó una columna `numero` que deberías reemplazar en tu código por la columna que tienen tus datos, es decir "ED. Cuenta de resultados. Residentes en España"

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Dante S. pero algo sigo haciendo mal porque no me funciona.  Antes de ejecutar el código que me has facilitado, compruebo el tipo de dato de la columna "Concepto" de la siguiente forma: pyg_agregada.dtypes y el resultado me dice lo siguiente:  "Concepto datetime64[ns]". Luego escribo tú código, pero me da el siguiente error: "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values". ¿Por qué me da este error si la columna "Concepto" es del tipo datetime64[ns]?

Comment: Quizá se deba a que precisamente ese tipo de dato no es compatible con dt. Pero es una suposición, supongo que @HeytalePazguato (que sabe más que yo) sabe la causa.

Comment: Jaja, noo, apenas estoy aprendiendo pandas. Según lo que encontré en una búsqueda rápida eso se debe a que al convertir la fecha en tipo datetime puede haber alguna fila que no se convierta correctamente. Intenta convertir con `pd.to_datetime(df['concepto'], errors='coerce')`. Podría ser que una fila esté un poco diferente en "Concepto"

Comment: @HeytalePazguato creo que somos 2 xDDDD